From Keras to Pytorch
I would like to write a ResNet50 pretrained model with Pytorch. So How can I transform this code writen with tensorflow and keras to Pytorch
resnet_model = ResNet50(
    include_top = False,
    weights = 'imagenet',
    input_shape = (224,224,3)
)

for layer in resnet_model.layers:
    if isinstance(layer, BatchNormalization):
        layer.trainable = True
    else:
        layer.trainable = False
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(7, 7),interpolation='bilinear'))
model.add(resnet_model)
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(.25))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='softmax'))

I try this :
class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.network = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
         ...
        
    def forward(self, xb):
        return self.network(xb)


So you've asked a few questions here, I'd encourage you to break it down. The first question is "how do I get rid of the classifying layers in a ResNet50 (includes_top = False in TensorFlow/Keras), and ptrblk explains that all you have to do is redefine model.fc as a nn.Module that just returns its input, or model.fc = nn.Linear(in, out). Then you're asking about how to freeze all weights except for the batch normalization layers. Then you're asking about adding modules to the end of an existing module.
